# SQL Group function query?

Tags: sql, oracle

The below sql code gives me ora - Invalid Number error.
How do i solve this ?
I guess its related to group by function.

```
SELECT SUM(RAT_CCY_SELL)/COUNT(dat_last_upd) 
FROM  RD_FCY_RATE_HIST  
WHERE cod_ccy ='EUR' 
AND   to_char( pk_ba_global.dat_process,'mm') - to_char(DAT_LAST_UPD,'mm')='1';
```

Comment: Where is group by in your query? what's the data in table and what's expected value?

Comment: I'm not down with plsql, but are you really supposed to do mathematical operations on the result of a `to_char` function?

Comment: I am wanting to have the the total sum of the currency rates / number of rows for the the current month where currency is selected as Euro.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the WHERE clause?

Comment: If you remove the `AND...` part, are you still receiving the error?

Comment: You probably want: `AND  extract(month from pk_ba_global.dat_process) - extract(month from DAT_LAST_UPD) = 1;`  But there is no table `pk_ba_global` in your query.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the  error is because of subtraction of two strings.

Some info from this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php) are following

### **Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-01722 Error Message**

**Cause**

```
 You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, 
but it was unsuccessful.
```

**Resolution**

```
The option(s) to resolve this Oracle error are:

Option #1
----------
Only numeric fields or character fields that contain 
numeric values can be used in arithmetic operations.
Make sure that all expressions evaluate to numbers.

Option #2
-----------
If you are adding or subtracting from dates, 
make sure that you added/substracted a numeric value from the date.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the average function `AVG` here:

```
SELECT
    AVG(RAT_CCY_SELL) 
FROM
    RD_FCY_RATE_HIST  
WHERE
    cod_ccy = 'EUR' AND
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm') = TO_CHAR(DAT_LAST_UPD, 'yyyy-mm')
```

I assumed here that the column `DAT_LAST_UPD` contains the date for each record with regard to determining what data corresponds to the current month.  If not, then replace that column.